# Different matrix row operations give different results

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hello I am new to linear algebra, and I have this question

\begin{equation*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 6\\
 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & -3 & 10\\
-2 & -2 & 2 & -3 & 6 & -12
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

I am supposed to reduce to row echelon form, which I did. Steps:

R2 = R2 + R3

R3 = R3 + R1

R3 = R3 - R2

which I get

\begin{equation*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 6\\
 0 & 0 & 3 & -1 & 3 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -4
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

however the answer key looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2pIA.png), which is different. Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row echelon form is not in general unique, i.e., there often exist multiple distinct row echelon forms for matrices. Therefore, your solution method is just as valid as the one used in the answer key. Actually, using your method, the third row should be

\begin{equation*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -4
\end{array}\right),
\end{equation*}

but the reasoning you use is correct.

Also, it is worthwhile to learn how to correctly format your mathematical expressions when asking questions. I edited your question to format the first matrix as an example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I hope you don't mind a quick follow up question : when solving the system of equations represented by the matrix, does it matter if I use the row echlon form or the reduced row echlon form? For example you mentioned there are multiple distinct row echelon forms. So do I have to use the reduced row form since there are multiple different row echelon forms?

Comment: Even though there might be different row echelon forms, they all correspond to the same solution set! Reducing the matrix even further to reduced-row echelon form (which *is* unique for a given matrix) just makes it easier to pick out the solutions more immediately, but they're the same solutions you'd get with any row-echelon forms.

Comment: Ah I see I see, thank you so much and have a good night!